# Chrome extension alarm not being triggered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I am working on a Chrome extension that needs to make use of chrome.alarms. The problem is that the alarm is not being triggered or is being triggered with a very inconsistent behavior.

The extension is build based on objects that live inside *event pages*, as recommended in *Manifest v2*. Also, I have tab events in the extension, that sometimes *wake up* the *event pages*.

Please help me create a *chrome.alarm* that actually gets triggered roughly every *n* minutes, or explain to me what I am doing wrong, or suggest an alternative.

Below, you can find the *relevant* pieces of code.

**manifest.json**

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "alarms"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/backend/monitor.js",
      "js/backend/bootstrap.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

**bootstrap.js**

```js
// Exaggerating with the validation on purpose
chrome.alarms.get('timeToSendToApi', function(alarm) {
  if (typeof alarm === 'undefined' || alarm.name !== 'timeToSendToApi') {
    chrome.alarms.create('timeToSendToApi', {periodInMinutes: 2});
  }
});
Main.monitor.start();
```

**monitor.js**

```js
Main.monitor = (function() {

  function send() {
    // Do stuff
  }    

  function tabUpdatedHandler(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  function tabActivatedHandler(activeInfo) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  function focusLost() {
    // Do stuff
  }

  function start(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( tabUpdatedHandler );
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( tabActivatedHandler );
    chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener( focusLost );
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
      if(alarm.name === 'timeToSendToApi') {
        send();
      }
    });    
  }

  return {
    start: start
  };
}());
```

Comment: You haven't described the inconsistent behavior, so it's hard to guess for sure what's wrong. While we have you here, have you compared your code to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101569/chrome-extension-alarms-go-off-when-chrome-is-reopened-after-time-runs-out/14102365#14102365 and http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#event-page-example?

Comment: The inconsistent behavior is that the event handler is triggered at irregular intervals. Sometimes, the event handler isn't being called for hours. It's  like the alarm is working in bursts and is unreliable. I suspect it has something to do with the "event pages" transient behavior, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely you've hit an issue that we just noticed in the code. About four months ago, [a change landed](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/23205008/diff/9001/chrome/browser/extensions/api/alarms/alarm_manager.cc) that we now understand could have caused the behavior you're seeing. Given that you saw this in November, you were probably on the dev or canary channel.

Sorry for the hassle; we'll get this fixed ASAP and possibly merged into broader channels.

Comment: Has the fix been implemented yet? I'm getting the same inconsistent behavior on Chrome Beta 32.0.1700.77

Comment: This issue still exists in Chrome 81.0.4044.138, in 2020. When I use chrome.alarms.getAll(), I can get the alarm which was just created. But it wasn't triggered when the time has elapsed.